# Swift Trying to print an element of a dictionary made from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I believe that the `jsonArray["success"]`  is returning to me that it is nil. because when I ran it without the `if` case it returned that it was nil. But I don't get why its doing that when there is data in the array

```
if let data = data {
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
  do {
      if let jsonArray = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String: Any]{
          print(jsonArray)
          if let success = jsonArray["success"] as? String {
              print(jsonArray)
              print(success) //BOOKMARK: Success displays that it is null....why?! 10-13-2017, 12:49
              print("foo")
          }
                    
      }
                
  }
  catch{
      //TODO tell user something didnt work
      print(error)
                
  }
}
//handle reading all json
        
})
```

Below is what I received when the `if` case was not implemented:

> {"success":0,"message":"User not found or wrong password"}
>
> ["message": User not found or wrong password, "success": 0]
>
> nil
>
> foo

Comment: Provide here, output/console print log for all of these stements, ` print(jsonArray)
                    if let success = jsonArray["success"] as? String {
                        print(jsonArray)
                        print(success) //BOOKMARK: Success displays that it is null....why?! 10-13-2017, 12:49
                        print("foo")
                    }`

Comment: `jsonArray` is not an array its a dictionary

Comment: Try printing your data `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? “”)` instead of `print("I am here")` edit your question and add it there

Comment: Btw success it is probably a Bool that’s been stored as NSNumber. So try casting it `as? Bool`

Comment: @LeoDabus so I tried printing the data like you said and casting it as a Boolean. Below is the print log

`{"success":0,"message":"User not found or wrong password"}
["message": User not found or wrong password, "success": 0]
Optional(false)
foo`

Comment: You still casting it to string that’s why it fails and prints nil